# Linux: sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `.'

Tags: linux, bash, sed, circleci

I am using a Linux container on CircleCI with an image of `circleci/node:11.14.0` and coming across an error when trying to run a sed command.

Code:

```
sed -i 's/<script>!f.*"dataLayer")<\/script>/<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow,noimageindex,noarchive" \/>/' build/index.html
sed -i 's/<noscript><iframe.*iframe><\/noscript>//' build/index.html
```

Error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `.'
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `.'
```

I can run this without errors on my Mac (need to add '.bak' after -i), so I am not understanding why it doesn't work on CircleCI? I have tried to escape the special characters without any luck.

Comment: Why is there a `Linux: ` in front of the error message? It should work as it is, the script is ok - search somewhere else. How do you execute it?

Comment: I execute it in a bash script, by calling ./scripts/my_script_file

Comment: If you have `/` characters in the pattern, it is typical to use a different delimiter.  eg `sed -e 's@<script>....@@'` so that you do not have to escape all the forward-slashes.

Comment: Thank you @WilliamPursell, that worked perfectly. Are you able to explain why? I assume it has something to do with the conflicting characters.

Comment: Both of these commands work fine for me as is. Which version of `sed` are you using?

Comment: I’m not sure - which ever version is used for the Linux container (last checked 28/9/19).